# TabControl , Frame in WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, uinavigationcontroller

In wpf , I was used to show a page into a frame after clicking on a tab item . Something like this :

```
<Frame Source = "" />
```

I added System.Windows.Controls reference in my project in order to work with tabControl & frame . I can add a tabControl , but no luck with Frame . My xaml code  :

```
xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
```

Whenever i'm trying to add a frame , compiler asks me to check the reference. What's the solution here ? Can anybody help ?

P.S. I know that in win Phone , pivotControl is the default tool , but my boss is demanding tabControl .

Comment: Maybe a better question would be "How do I convince my boss I shouldn't be using a TabControl in a WP7 app?"